# How can return a QList or Qobject directly from Q_INVOKABLE method to a var or Qtobject of Qml (without using model)?

Tags: qt, qml

I wanna return a QList or Qobject from Q_INVOKABLE
method to a var or Qtobject of Qml but it doesn’t work While the setContextProperty for a QList works.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    QList<qreal> myList {0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myList", QVariant::fromValue(myList));
    DataModel* dataModel = new DataModel("location",20.14,21.54,"green");
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myData", QVariant::fromValue(dataModel));
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
...
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "QList<qreal>"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("QList by loop:");
                for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; ++i)
                {
                    console.log(myList[i]);
                }
                console.log("QList by index:");
                console.log(myList[0],", ",myList[1],", ",myList[2],", ",myList[3]);
            }
        }
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "DataModel*"
            property QtObject obj
            onClicked: {
                var obj = myData.getObject()
                //OR
                obj = myData.getObject()
                console.log("name=", obj.name,",lat=", obj.latitude,",long=", obj.longitude,",color=", obj.color);
            }
        }
    }

...
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, which Q_INVOKABLE do you mean? Also explain what you want based on your example.

Comment: The Question is not clear .. and not focused .. please edit your question to relate to subject title .. and remove unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should know about Qml data types. [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-typesystem-basictypes.html) says:

> Basic Types Provided By The QML Language
>
> The basic types supported natively in the QML language are listed below:
> bool
> Binary
> true/false
> value
> double
> Number with a decimal point, stored in double precision
> enumeration Named enumeration value int Whole number, e.g. 0, 10, or
> -20 list List of QML objects real Number with a decimal point string Free form > text string url Resource locator var Generic property type
>
> Basic Types Provided By QML Modules
>
> QML modules may extend the QML
> language with more basic types. For example, the basic types provided
> by the QtQuick module are listed below:  date Date value point Value
> with x and y attributes rect Value with x, y, width and height
> attributes size Value with width and height attributes The Qt global
> object provides useful functions for manipulating values of basic
> types.

So you can pass Qml simple supported types like int, doble, bool, etc. and every QList with supported types like QList, QList, QStringList and etc.
Also you can pass a QObject to Qml but you should know that simple supported types can be assigned to Qml var type directly but QList and QObject must be passed to a JavaScript function. About it [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object) says:

> QVariantList and QVariantMap to JavaScript Array and Object
>
> The QML
> engine provides automatic type conversion between QVariantList and
> JavaScript arrays, and between QVariantMap and JavaScript objects.

The following link will help you achieve what you want:

You can view or download the codes from github by this [link](https://github.com/MohammadMazaheri/MySnipCodes/tree/main/QListToQml).

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    QList<qreal> myList {0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myList", QVariant::fromValue(myList));
    DataModel* dataModel = new DataModel("location",20.14,21.54,"green");
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myData", QVariant::fromValue(dataModel));
    QStringList strList {"H","e","l","l","o"};
    DataModelList* dataModelList = new DataModelList(strList);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myDataList", QVariant::fromValue(dataModelList));
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 240
    height: 120
    title: qsTr("Scroll")
    function readObject(obj) {
        console.log("DataModel by calling function:");
        console.log(obj.name,obj.latitude,obj.longitude,obj.color);
    }
    function readList(list) {
        console.log("DataModelList by calling function:");
        for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
            console.log(list[i])
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "QList<qreal>"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("QList by loop:");
                for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; ++i)
                {
                    console.log(myList[i]);
                }
                console.log("QList by index:");
                console.log(myList[0],", ",myList[1],", ",myList[2],", ",myList[3]);
            }
        }
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "DataModel*"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("DataModel by fields:");
                console.log("name=",myData.name,",lat=",myData.latitude,",long=",myData.longitude,",color=",myData.color);
                readObject(myData.getObject())
            }
        }
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "DataModelList*"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("DataModelList by fields:");
                console.log(myDataList. StrList[0], myDataList.strList[1], myDataList.strList[2], myDataList.strList[3], myDataList.strList[4]);
                readList(myDataList.getList())
                console.log("DataModelList count by calling function:");
                var count = myDataList.getListCount()
                console.log("count=",count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```